# g++ can't find .so files in /usr/local/lib/ even when added to /etc/ld.so.conf, and ldconfig having been run

Tags: g++

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. 
I have a C++ source file `second.cpp` which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

int main(){
    bfs::path p("second.cpp");
    if (bfs::exists(p))
        std::cout << p.leaf() << std::endl;
}
```

When I run `$ g++ -o second second.cpp`, I get the following:

> /tmp/ccyWlRx6.o: In function `boost::filesystem::path::leaf() const':
>   second.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost10filesystem4path4leafEv[_ZNK5boost10filesystem4path4leafEv]+0x2e): undefined reference to`boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
>   /tmp/ccyWlRx6.o: In function `boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
>   second.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE[_ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE]+0x2f): undefined reference to`boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

However, if I run `g++ -o second second.cpp -lboost_filesystem`, the code compiles with no errors. `libboost_filesystem.a`, `libboost_filesystem.so`, and `libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0` are all in `/usr/local/lib`.

`/etc/ld.so.conf` looks like this:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
```

and I have run `sudo ldconfig`.

Is this the normal behavior? From what I have read, it seemed to me like the files in `/usr/local/lib` should automatically be included by the linker. If this is not the case, is there I way that I can achieve this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: The loader configuration has nothing to do with the linker.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the normal behavior?

Of course it is.  If you do not tell the compiler driver with `-l boost_filesystem` to even look for the library to link with it, it will not do so and your program which uses the library will not link, as you have seen.  Your compiler is not magic.  If your program needs to link in a library other than the C/C++/GCC runtime libraries that the compiler knows about by default, you need to tell the compiler about the library.

The title of your question is a falsehood.  As you have observed …

> I run `g++ -o second second.cpp -lboost_filesystem`, the code compiles with no errors.

… g++ *does* find the library in `/usr/local/lib`: once you do things properly and actually tell it the name of the library to look for.

Also note that discussion of `-L` is a red herring for the same reason.  You didn't use `-L` and yet g++ found the library *anyway*; so there is obviously no problem with the directory containing the library not being in the compiler's default library search path.

Since you have not even attempted to *run* the program, according to your question, whether the dynamic loader finds that library there is unknown.  But it probably will.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear: Is there a way for g++ to find library without passing passing `-l` or must this be done each time I compile a new program using the library? I should have mentioned that the program does run (although the if block was causing a segmentation fault).

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you need to specify the Linker search path whenever you like to link from a nonstandard directory.

Comment: Okay. What exactly does standard mean here? Something like <iostream>?

Answer (score -1):

If you like to let the linker find a library at an unusual location, you need to use a `-L` option to specify the directory, the library is in.

If you like the runtime linker to find the same library at runtime, use the `-R` for the linker to add a `RUNPATH` tag to the binary.

ldconfig was used in the 1980s with the `a.out` format because it did not have the `RUNPATH` property that was added to `ELF`.

Answer (score -1):

I assume it seems you need to create a configuration file under the /etc/ld.so.conf.d
 instead of adding the entry into  /etc/ld.so.conf.

/etc/ld.so.conf reads all configuration files from /etc/ld.so.conf.d
directory which contains configuration files of library path to library files.
The configuration file name is not defined by system, so you can name it
 whatever you want like `locallib.conf` for example.
So, somthing like this,

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/locallib.conf
```

Contains
    `/usr/local/lib`

Then after run `ldconfig`.

Another way.
This is only enabled local environment(not system global).
Adding an entry of library path to your `.bashrc`.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Enabling the environment variables by 
`. ./.bashrc`.
Please don't forget to check out the variables with followed command.

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: The questioner has already stated that the program both compiled and ran without doing _any_ of that.